# Bitmap Share Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I am trying to convert entire CardView into an Image and then I want to share it using different apps.

**PROBLEM**

```
cardView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        cardView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        cardView.layout(0,0, cardView.getMeasuredWidth(), cardView.getMeasuredHeight());
        cardView.buildDrawingCache(true);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cardView.getDrawingCache());
        cardView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(DetailedActivity.this.getContentResolver(),bitmap,"quote",null);
        uri = Uri.parse(path);
```

Thing is I am getting cardview converted into bitmap but while getting uri from bitmap it is returning null path. so while converting Uri it is giving NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.

*Below is the list of **permissions** I provided.*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"
                        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

**CardView XML**
If I give the CardView a defined hardcoded values for Height and Width of a CardView it is working but when I use

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

With the code shown above it is giving NULL_POINTER_EXCEPTION.

**QUERIES**

*1. How can I make it work?*

*2. Is there any other way to do this?*

Comment: It is returning 1158 and 304for width and height respectively.

Comment: I guess you got it wrong. In every case I am getting those values but in every case I am getting path NULL as well.

Answer (score 0):

So if I get it right, the URI path is stored in uri variable. The null error happens because you didn't initialise that uri string. You can do this:

```
String uri = new String() // -> if there is still an error here, replace String() with String(this) or String(activity_your_name.this)
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity_output.class); // -> here you add the activity where you send the URI to
intent.putExtra("URI", uri);
```

and on the other activities you extract the URI through:

```
//Getting the URI from previous activity:
path =  getIntent().getExtra("URI");
//Initialising the File form your URI
File StringToBitmap = new File;
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
StringToBitmap = new File(path, String.valueOf(options));
//Your bitmap will be stored in mBitmaps
mBitmaps = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
//The next part is extra, if you want to display your bitmap into an ImageView
ImageView iv = new ImageView();
iv = findViewById(R.id.your_id);
iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmaps);
```

This code worked to me for something very similar. And about that NULL EXCEPTION, every time you get it, try to see if you initialised all your objects correctly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }

public void onShareImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String fileName = "IMG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".PNG";
    storeScreenShot(bitmap, fileName);
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(VarName.SCREENSHOT_DIRECTORY + "/" + fileName));

    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, VarName.DRESS_ME_SHARE_MASSAGE_HEADER + "\n" + VarName.DRESS_ME_SHARE_APP_LINK);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
}

public void storeScreenShot(Bitmap bm, String fileName) {

    File dir = new File(VarName.SCREENSHOT_DIRECTORY);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), ".nomedia");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            final Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    File file = new File(VarName.SCREENSHOT_DIRECTORY, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        file.createNewFile();
        final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        final Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now you Just need to call function.

```
Bitmap bitmap = getScreenShot(cardView);
onShareImage(bitmap);
```